# Use xhtml namespaces in xsd problem

Tags: xml, xhtml, xsd

I want to make in my xml file something like that:

```
<myfile>
<screen>
<img src="a.jpg"/>
</screen>
</myfile>
```

I try to make this in this way:
**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

          <myfile  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="myfile.xsd">

<screen>
<img src="a.jpg"/>
</screen>
</myfile>
```

**XSD file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsd:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" schemaLocation="xhtml.xsd"/>
<xsd:element name="myfile">
<xsd:element name="screen">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element ref="xhtml:img"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:element>
```

But firefox dont display any error, but i can't see any image :/
Can someone help with this ?

Answer (score 2):

**Displaying images**

Firefox, as a browser, displays web pages written in XHTML or HTML. In that situation, it will display images marked up as `<img>` elements.

Otherwise, it does not do anything special with `<img>` elements. For example, if you have `<img>` elements in the middle of your own custom XML document, Firefox knows nothing of what it is.

The solution is, in order to have the image display properly, to create [an XHTML document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML).

**Namespaces**

Since you asked specifically about namespaces... your XML document will not validate against your schema because your schema is expecting elements in the XHTML namespace, but the elements in your XML document are in no namespace.

To fix that, change the following line of your XML document

```
<myfile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="myfile.xsd">
```

to

```
<myfile xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="myfile.xsd">
```

The default namespace declaration `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` says "this element, and all descendants, that don't have a namespace prefix, are in the XHTML namespace."

Note that *being in a certain namespace* and *being validated by a certain schema* are independent properties of an XML document. (Actually the former is a property of an element or attribute, not of the whole document.) Schemas *use* namespaces, but the two are not the same.

Comment: But what happens when in my xml i have for example, <title> element ? It use descrition from my xsd or xhtml ?

Comment: When you say "it use description" are you talking about validation? The purpose of XSD is validation. You do not have to have an XSD file in order to have an XHTML document that works in browsers. If you do need to validate your XHTML document, you can use http://validator.w3.org/ or you can use a DTD (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xhtml#DOCTYPEs). Using a schema (XSD) is not recommended, so I would get rid of the xmlns:xsi and xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation attributes.